# ReactJS when Modal Popup onClose refresh item on page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi i use react bootstrap modal. On my page I have a `<selectList />` component, which lists categories.  I have an Add+ button near it. When I click add, I  open the `<CategoryAdd />` component in the modal. When I add categories, I call the close method and it updates the `isDataChangeKey` value and passes it to `selectList`.  `selectList` checks the value and if required, refreshes  with an ajax call and populates data.  I think I am doing this the hard way.  Is there any easy way of doing this?

My Way:

InitialState:

```js
getInitialState: function() {
  var initial = {
     "isDataChangeKey ": 0
  };
  return initial;
},
```

Main Page:

```html
   <div className="col-xs-4">
     <SelectList
       nullable={true}
       dataStateKey={this.state.isDataChangeKey}
       dataUrl="/Category/GetAll"
       defaultValue={this.state.CategoryID}
       id="CategoryID"
       name="CategoryID"
       optionValue="CategoryID"
       optionText="CategoryName"
     />
   </div>

   <div className="col-xs-2">
     <ModalTrigger
       modal={
         <ModelComponent
           componentName={CategoryAdd}
           onClose={this.handlePopupClose.bind(null,'category')}
         />}
     >
       <a
         data-toggle="modal"
         href="#deleteModal"
         className="btn btn-orange btn-icon bottom15 right15"
       >
         <i className="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; <span>Add+</span>
       </a>
     </ModalTrigger>
   </div>
```

Handle PopUpClose:

```js
 handlePopupClose: function(popUpName){
   var that = this;
   if (popUpName == 'category') {
     this.setState({"isDataChangeKey ": this.state.isDataChangeKey +1});
     console.log("Modal Closed");
   }
```

In Select Component:

```js
componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.dataStateKey != this.props.dataStateKey) {
    this.getAjaxData();
  }
},
```

Comment: Try putting this in a jsfiddle for better feedback.